# Calculating power received and V (rms) given powr loss

Tags: voltage, power, transmission-line, loss

The transmission line cable below is 10m long and has a power loss of 1 dB/m at the frequency of the source. What is the power received at the receiver (in dBm), and the voltage (RMS) of the signal at the receiver in \$dB\mu V\$?

[image]

Here's what I have:

\$P_{in} - P_{out}\$ = Power loss

Power received at receiver = -30dBm - (10)(1) = -40dBm

-40dBm = \$10^{-4}\$ mW = \$10^{-7}\$ W

\$P = \frac{V_{RMS}^2}{R} = 10^{-7}\$

\$V_{RMS} = \sqrt{10^{-7} (300)} = 0.005477 V = 5477\mu V\$

\$V_{RMS} = 20log_{10}(5477) = 74.77\:dB\mu V\$

Are my calculations correct?

Comment: You have a "2" popping in from somewhere I don't understand.

Comment: In \$2V_{RMS}^2\$? That's because \$V/\sqrt{2} = V_{RMS}\$. So moving it to the other side, and squaring it gives the "2".

Comment: Power is RMS voltage squared divided by resistance.

Comment: I've made some changes based on what you said about the power. Are my calculations correct now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the 5.477 mV and this translates to 74.77 dBuV. Yes I now agree with your corrected calculations.